# group by class multiple category variables in R

Tags: r

I am extremely new to R and thus not familiar with the various packages.

I am simply using Soybean data from library(mlbench) data(Soybean) and I want visualize in a table the CLASS factor (19 levels) by various categories (date, plant.stand, precip, etc) (there are 35 such vars). I want to show frequency, NAs and mode.  In essence then each Class would then be broken out by the various category (date, plant.stand, precip) etc with the frequency data.

I' sure there must be a simple way but I'm very new to R.

Thanks for the help.

Update

As per the table below:

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQwUS.png)

I want to basically count all the categorical data ie (date, plant.stand, precip, etc) and sort by CLASS variable.  The only way I can think of is by creating a key for each factor level per categorical variable, counting the occurrence of each key and then sorting.  Is there perhaps an easier way?

Comment: You can use `library(dplyr); Soybean %>% group_by(CLASS) %>% summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), yourfunc)`.  also, there is `summaryBy` function in `doBy` which will get the ssummary statistics by the grouping column

Comment: Your expected output is not very clear though

Comment: May be `Soybean %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(~ list(freq = table(.), no_Nas = sum(is.na(.)), mode = Mode(.))))`

Comment: what does %>% mean in dplyr?  Basically say type=a,b,c and categories=1,2,3 I want to show (A-1:  freq, nulls, A-2: freq, nulls A-3: freq, nulls) then (B-1: freq, nulls), etc.  basically break down each type by the category and show the count stats and NAs

Comment: If you are checking for some `EDA`, you can check `smartEDA` https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04754.pdf or with [DataExplorer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/vignettes/dataexplorer-intro.html)

Comment: the code above didn't work, the error outputted by r is "ERROR: column 'date' must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2" when date is a Factor with 7 levels?

Comment: For me, that was working with `R 3.6.2` and the dev version of `dplyr`

Comment: For me, unfortunately, it fails with R-3.5.3 and CRAN `dplyr`.